# On keyup selector, but not if the selector has a child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a universal selector for a keyup-event of all text-related HTML-elements:

```
$('.dashboard_container').on('keyup', 'p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, strong', function(){});
```

There is only one exception: if the selected element has a child, e.g. 'strong', the event must not be triggered.

I tried the following:

```
1. $('.dashboard_container').on('keyup', 'p:not(p>*), h1:not(h1>*), h2:not(h2>*), h3:not(h3>*), h4:not(h4>*), h5:not(h5>*), strong:not(strong>*)', function(){})
2. if($(this).children().length <= 0) {}
```

Both which do not work the way I want them to work.
If the element has a child, the event must not be triggered!

Comment: Is `if(THAT.children` a copy error ? Should be `this`

Comment: Yes it is, my code is a lot more complicated than this example, I will change it... My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you could use [:has](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) jQuery selector (and [:header](https://api.jquery.com/header-selector/) one):

```
$('.dashboard_container').on('keyup', 'p:not(:has(*)), :header:not(:has(*)), strong:not(:has(*))', handler);
```

And if you just want to exclude any kind of type of element which has some content, you can use:

```
$('.dashboard_container').on('keyup', '*:not(:has(*))', handler);
```

Comment: Awesome! I used the 'p:not(:has(*))' example and it works great! Thank you.